# How to Upload Image & Text Together in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have successfully uploaded images and text separately or one by one, but I have trouble to experiment upload images and text simultaneously, is there a solution ??

Comment: Please show what you have already tried so we can continue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uncertain regarding how to mimic this or that request you can just **record** it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). JMeter should be smart enough to capture the request and populate the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration.

Just keep in mind one hint: put the file(s) you will be uploading using browser in JMeter's "bin" folder, this way JMeter will be able to intercept the requests. See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details.